# Почему один индекс Sphinx возвращает атрибуты вместе со значениями, другой - нет?

Tags: php, sphinx

В моем конфиге настроены 2 индекса на индексацию 2-х таблиц MySQL:

```
#medicalfacilities
source medicalfacilities : lsParentSource
{   

    sql_query_range = SELECT MIN(idMedicalFacilities), MAX(idMedicalFacilities) FROM 

medicalfacilities
    sql_range_step  = 128

    sql_query       = SELECT idMedicalFacilities * 10 + 1 as id, 2000 as type, 

idmedicalfacilities, MedicalFacilitiesName, medicalfacilitiesiduser, medicalfacilitiessite, 

medicalfacilitiesemail, medicalfacilitiesphoto FROM medicalfacilities WHERE 

idMedicalFacilities>=$start AND idMedicalFacilities<=$end

    sql_attr_uint    = idmedicalfacilities
    sql_attr_uint     = type
    sql_attr_uint    = MedicalFacilitiesIdUser
    sql_field_string = MedicalFacilitiesSite
    sql_field_string = MedicalFacilitiesName
    sql_field_string = MedicalFacilitiesPhoto
    sql_field_string = MedicalFacilitiesEmail
    sql_query_info     = SELECT MedicalFacilitiesName, MedicalFacilitiesDescription \
                         FROM medicalfacilities WHERE idMedicalFacilities = ($id - 1) / 10

    # Время засыпания в миллисекундах (sleep) перед отправкой запросов серверу (может быть 

полезно для разгрузки сервера базы данных)
    sql_ranged_throttle = 0
}



#users
source users : lsParentSource
{

    sql_query_range   = SELECT MIN(idDetailToUsers), MAX(idDetailToUsers) FROM detailtousers
    sql_query         = SELECT idDetailToUsers as id, 1000 as type, UsersTypeAccount, 

idDetailToUsers, SpecializationName, DetailToUsersName, DetailToUsersPhoto, city, country FROM 

detailtousers join users ON users.idUsers = detailtousers.idDetailToUsers left join 

usersspecialization ON usersspecialization.UsersSpecializationIdUser = 

detailtousers.idDetailToUsers left join specializationtousers ON 

specializationtousers.idSpecialization = usersspecialization.UsersSpecializationIdSpecialization 

WHERE idDetailToUsers >= $start AND idDetailToUsers <= $end GROUP BY idDetailToUsers

    sql_attr_uint     = type
    sql_attr_uint     = idDetailToUsers
    sql_attr_uint     = UsersTypeAccount
    sql_field_string  = SpecializationName
    sql_field_string  = DetailToUsersName
    sql_field_string  = DetailToUsersPhoto
    sql_attr_uint     = city
    sql_attr_uint     = country

    sql_query_info    = SELECT idDetailToUsers, DetailToUsersName, UsersTypeAccount, 

SpecializationName, DetailToUsersPhoto, city, country \
                        FROM detailtousers WHERE idDetailToUsers = $id
    sql_ranged_throttle = 0
}
```

**Индексы:**

```
index medicalfacilities {
    source = medicalfacilities
    path = /var/data/sphinx/medicalfacilities
    #enable_star = 1 
    charset_type        = utf-8
    html_strip = 1
    #morphology = stem_ru
    min_word_len = 3
    min_prefix_len = 3
    #min_infix_len = 3
}

index users_index {
    docinfo       = extern
    source = users
    path = /var/data/sphinx/users
    charset_type  = utf-8
    html_strip    = 1
    morphology    = stem_enru
    min_word_len            = 1
    min_prefix_len          = 0
    min_infix_len           = 1
    enable_star = 1
}
```

Для индекса `users` возвращаются атрибуты со значениями, а для `medicalfacilities` - без.

Comment: Попробуйте выполнить запрос "sql_query" непосредственно в базе. Там точно есть все значения, которые вы выбрали?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

На первый взгляд проблема в этой части

```
    sql_query_info     = SELECT MedicalFacilitiesName, MedicalFacilitiesDescription \
                     FROM medicalfacilities WHERE idMedicalFacilities = ($id - 1) / 10
```

Зачем нужно выражение `($id - 1) / 10` ? Может заменить его на `$id`?

Кроме того у сфинкса есть SphinxQL. Т.е. можно писать запросы в него как в MySQL. Работает по протоколу mysql(т.е. можно присоединиться обычным mysql клиентом по указанному порту).

http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/latest/sphinxql.html